# Android Fragments - newInstance() vs instantiate() method

Tags: android, android-fragments

Are there any (dis-)advantages to use the `instantiate()` method for loading new `Fragments`? Or is it only on personal taste?

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.puString(...);
args....
Fragment newFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, fragmentName, args);
```

vs.

```
//... 
NewFragment instance = NewFragment.newInstance(String param1, String param2);
//....
    public static NewFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `newInstance()` is preferable if you have arguments that must be provided to the Fragment, as it's easy to see which parameters are needed, and you don't have to worry about creating a bundle and knowing which keys to use.

If your Fragment takes no arguments, then just avoid it altogether and make it with the default constructor, i.e. `new MyFragment()`.